# Why is variable not changing in a PHP array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I am trying to assemble an `array` of objects from a variety of sources in PHP (I'm new to the language). The problem is that I am not able to store the data within the `$bandwidthData` `array` in the `foreach` loop I am trying to write.

```
private function _getData($startDay, $totalDays)
{
    $devices = ubntDevices::getDevices();
    $data = [];
    $bandwidthData = [];
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        $bandwidthData[$count]['device'] = $device;
        $bandwidthData[$count]['bandwidth'] = new ubntModel($device->file);
        $bandwidthData[$count]['bandwidth']->getMonthData();
        $bandwidthData[$count]['tree'] = new graphTree($device->hostid);
        $bandwidthData[$count]['graphid'] = ubntGraph::getGraphByHostId($device->hostid);
        $bandwidthData[$count]['hostname'] = $device->host_name;
        $count++;
    }
    return $bandwidthData;
}
```

If I return from within the `foreach` loop, I get the correct output (but obviously for only the first device). I have tested all of the other `function` sources, and they seem to be returning the right data. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you enabled PHP errors? Possible that the `new` keyword returns a false object, thus, leading to a "perform object something or the other on a boolean", and resulting in an empty array.

Comment: That has been so of my biggest frustrations with using PHP, I cannot seem to debug it easily. Is there a way to see errors more easily using VS Code?

Comment: not sure about using VS Code, but [xdebug](http://xdebug.org) is available for step-through debugging :) a real life-send tbh

Comment: open a terminal and type `tail -f /apth/to/php/error_log`, your errors will scroll past in real time

Comment: To make it easier to debug, you can create an object which contains all the values (from 'device' to 'hostname'), trace the object and then add it to the bandwidthData array.

Comment: Does `_getData()` simply return an empty array? Btw, what does `$bandwidthData[$count]['bandwidth']->getMonthData()` do?

Comment: It is taking me a few minutes to figure out installing extensions php, I am currently trying to get xdebug. Thank you for all of the suggestions so far, I will get back to you in a bit.

Comment: What does `ubntDevices::getDevices()` return?

Comment: ubntDevices::getDevices() returns an array of objects similar to as follows: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [hostid] => 4320 [customer_name] => Customer Name (removed for privacy) [file] => /var/lib/cacti/rra/4320/69644.rrd [host_name] => 172.xx.xxx.xx )

Comment: @rfdev sorry just for clarification it returns an array of objects, it is not an iterator?

Comment: Try inserting `if($count ==1) break;` gradually from top to bottom in the foreach block.  And check your return.

Comment: Man, I think a lot of this is stemming from my lack of PHP knowledge. I am trying to adapt some legacy code to work in another context. That is the output, is that considered an iterator?

Comment: Woah, that worked gradually increasing the count with a break. So what does that mean?

Comment: Define: 'worked'.

Comment: Sorry, so when I added if($count ==1) break; it would give me that amount of devices  in my output until it hit the "count" .

Comment: Anyway this question is too generic: people can't help in troubleshooting this snippet, because the error is obviously not related to this snippet. You need to provide more code about the functions you are calling, and at least isolate the problem (in order to, in the other hand, do not have to post here the whole application)

Comment: Sorry, yeah thanks for the help. I was struggling with how to show things without violating privacy issues. This question can be closed, I will ask more specific question when I know what to ask. Thank you to everyone involved.

Comment: The count itself shouldn't pose an issue.  The idea of the break above, is to see if upon the second loop/iteration, there is a particular something causing an issue.  Perhaps it's a repeat function call issue, or too many loops/memory exhaustion etc.  Try to increase the count/break, does it work for a few loops?  You can delete your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP error log should indicate what's going wrong. XDebug is very highly recommended as well.
However, nowadays it is more common to use an associative array like this:

```
private function _getData($startDay, $totalDays)
{
    $devices = ubntDevices::getDevices();
    $bandwidthData = [];

    foreach ($devices as $device) {
        $ubntModel = new ubntModel($device->file);
        $deviceData = array('device' => $device,
                            'ubntModel' => $ubntModel,
                            'bandwidth' => $ubntModel->getMonthData(),
                            'tree' => new graphTree($device->hostid),
                            'graphid' => ubntGraph::getGraphByHostId($device->hostid),
                            'hostname' => $device->host_name);
        $bandwidthData[] = $deviceData;
    }
    return $bandwidthData;
}
```

Comment: I like this setup a lot better. I might refactor it this way to make it a lot cleaner. Thanks for the tip. Still trying to install xdebug. Sounds like everyone uses that who is working in PHP.

Comment: Yes, and the XDebug setup has been streamlined a lot. Their website can suggest the correct version, create installers, etc. There are other PHP debugger and profiler that are used for performance optimizations and such, e.g. XHProf. https://php.libhunt.com/xdebug-alternatives

Answer (score -2):

Some things I'm seeing:

Is this variable in use?

```
$data = [];
```

Also, this assignment runs but is a discouraged approach because at this point `$bandwidthData[$count]` does not exist:<sup>1</sup>

```
$bandwidthData[$count]['device'] = $device;
```

That can be converted to:

```
$bandwidthData[$count] = [ 'device' => $device ];
```

Also, this just a getter returning nowhere. Isn't it?

```
$bandwidthData[$count]['bandwidth']->getMonthData();
```

Also to further learn PHP I can suggest such cleaner approach for that code snippet, just to improve readability:

```
private function _getData( $startDay, $totalDays ) {
    $bandwidthData = [];

    foreach ( ubntDevices::getDevices() as $device ) {
        $bandwidthData[] = [
            'device'    => $device,
            'bandwidth' => new ubntModel( $device->file ),
            'tree'      => new graphTree( $device->hostid ),
            'graphid'   => ubntGraph::getGraphByHostId( $device->hostid ),
            'hostname'  => $device->host_name,
        ];
    }

    return $bandwidthData;
}
```

Anyway you have to learn how to debug that simple small block of code just looking at your server logs, or with a lazy `var_dump( $bandwidthData[ $count ] )` in your suspected line (do not fight about this debugging approach: it's super stupid, but dramatically simple and effective, and friendly for newcomers - if you have not the possibility to setup a debugger because maybe the server is not yours etc.) or setting up a debugger.

---

<sup>1</sup> from https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array

> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to initialize a variable by a direct assignment

Comment: `Also, this assignment is not correct because at this point $bandwidthData[$count] does not exist:` - not true, it'll still assign it (unless `$count` somehow goes awry): https://3v4l.org/1TNuX `$bandwidthData[$count]['bandwidth']->getMonthData();` - what's your theory/meaining behind this? tools to help debugging are always worth having, especially for loop work (or at least I like it as I can see the data being handled as I step through)

Comment: (lol you generated a short URL with FUK) anyway maybe I explained myself in a wrong way. It runs, it does not give any warning, but it's officially discouraged. I've updated the comment with a reference.